# Diode alternatives for LTspice

Tags: diodes, ltspice, pspice, circuits, voltage-clipping

I am using LTspice as opposed to P-spice because I have a Mac. I've been asked to simulate a circuit using 1N914 and 1N4729 diodes, but LTspice doesn't have those diodes. What are equivalent diodes to the ones previously mentioned on LTspice?

Comment: You should leave links to the data sheets and you should also state where you have looked for this answer already.

Comment: If you have "been asked" to simulate two specific diodes, don't you think you should discuss this with the person who asked you to do that? Are you reluctant to do that for some reason?

Answer (score 3):

`1N914` should be included in the default installation. I don't know how the list is displayed in the Mac version, but in Windows it's right at the top, the first entry:

```
.model 1N914 D(Is=2.52n Rs=.568 N=1.752 Cjo=4p M=.4 tt=20n Iave=200m Vpk=75 mfg=OnSemi type=silicon)
```

The other needed some digging on the web. I found a subcircuit [on this page](http://bordodynov.ltwiki.org/), not a `.model`, but it should work just fine:

```
*SRC=1N4729A;1N4729A;Diodes;Zener <=10V; 3.60V  1.00W   Diodes Inc. Zener
.SUBCKT 1N4729A_3.6V_1W  1 2
*        Terminals    A   K
D1 1 2 DF
DZ 3 1 DR
VZ 2 3 1.30
.MODEL DF D ( IS=114p RS=0.620 N=1.10 CJO=319p VJ=0.750 M=0.330 TT=50.1n )
.MODEL DR D ( IS=22.9f RS=0.923 N=3.00 )
.ENDS
```

In case you, or someone else looking at this answer doesn't know, to make this work, after placing the diode in the schematic, rename it to `1N4729A_3.6V_1W`, then `Ctrl+RClick` on the diode, and on the `Prefix` line replace `D` with `X`.

To make the subcircuit (the block of text above) available, press `S` in the schematic to bring up the SPICE directive dialog, paste the block of text above, then `LClick` to place it in the schematic. Or you could save it as a file, then add it with either a `.lib` or `.inc` directive.

The `1N914` doesn't need changing the prefix, only the name. The same copy-paste in the schematic can be used.

As usual, don't just trust blindly the models -- verify them to see they meet the requirements.